# Запятые при "как итог"

Tags: запятые

"Как итог" - это вводная конструкция? Когда она обособляется, а когда - нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это вводное словосочетание.

В книгах оно редко **вводное** (можно изъять без потери смысла):

`Как итог, почему бы не предположить, что он, как любой здравомыслящий и предвидящий ситуации человек, не попытался заранее перестраховаться?`

`Как итог, в марте 77-го лидер ФКП имел личную встречу с лидерами ИКП и КПИ, где выразил согласие со многими позициями апостолов еврокоммунизма.`

**Не вводное**, если нельзя изъять и **есть связь с другими словами**:

`И как итог этого — главный камень преткновения для сегодняшних промышленных предприятий это нехватка квалифицированных рабочих рук.`

`И как итог деятельности этого согласительного форума — мы пришли к этому Федеративному договору.`

`Коммуны как итог краха всей цивилизации.`

`Процессы, происходящие в экономике в результате управленческих действий, и состояние как итог этих процессов — таковы два связанных, но самостоятельных предмета исследования в настоящей работе.`

Comment: *Как итог(,) получаем, что сумма расходов первышает сумму доходов* - сможете обосновать пунктуацию согласно вашим  формулировкам?!

Comment: *В книгах оно редко вводное* - да?! А ваши примеры говорят об обратном.

Comment: Так я еле нашёл 2 примера с вводным. А без запятых (итог чего-то) валом.

Comment: А откуда это читающий знает?!

Comment: Что откуда? В вашем примере нужна запятая по-любому. Даже если "как подведённый итог". Но "Получаем, что сумма расходов превышает сумму доходов (в виде) как итог отчёта".

Comment: Понятно. Жаль не могу второй минус поставить, А надо бы. Первый - за изощренное издевательство над читающим, второй - за "по-любому".

Comment: Какое издевательство? Обороты с "как" выделяются в начале предложения. Это может быть сравнение, вводное. Без запятой - когда что-то выражается через что-то. Например: биология как наука; тезис как вывод; действие как решение; состояние как итог. Оно не может быть наоборот без запятой. Печально, что вы, давая ответы столько лет, не знаете таких элементарных вещей.

Comment: Издевательство - в формулировке. "оно редко вводное" означает, что дальше идут примеры ***частого*** употребления. Впрочем, по моим представлениям, "в книгах" **как итог** чаще всего - как раз таки обычное вводное. ))))

Comment: Совсем оно такое не означает. Странная у вас логика. После "редко вводное" ставлю двоеточие и привожу примеры этого "редкого", что удалось найти. Чего бы приводить примеры не вводного, если про него ещё даже не говорилось. Нет логики...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98085/discussion-between-behemothus-and-oleedd).

Answer (score 0):

Не хотел я отвечать на очередной умозрительный вопрос... Тем более не хотел, из-за того, что вопрос на грани закрытия, но вынужден.

Единственно правильным ответом тут будет тот, что "когда вводное, тогда и обособляется". А что вы вообще хотели услышать?!

Могу только добавить, что вводное в данном случае распознается очень просто. Если позволяет заменить на "в итоге", "итогом/результатом [имеем]", то вводным быть не может, ибо "в итоге" таковым почти никогда не бывает, ну разве что автор очень уж своеобразно изъясняется.
Иначе - почти наверняка вводное.

Критерий "можно изъять не нарушая смысла" здесь работает хуже, ибо "как итог" в роли члена предложения часто может быть удалено их текста почти без нарушения смысла.

Мой фрагмент из бухгалтерской практики - тому хороший пример. 
***Как итог получаем, что сумма расходов превышает сумму доходов***

Здесь речь скорее всего идет именно об итоге именно арифметических действий по сложению-вычитанию расходов-доходов (наверняка без контекста сказать нельзя), а не о **результате** каких-то умозаключений...

Сравните: ***Как итог по кассе получаем отрицательное сальдо.*** (= в кассовом итоге)

Бухгалтерией, разумеется, подобные спорные случаи не ограничиваются, но тут все предельно наглядно.

Comment: По этой причине я добавил, что нельзя изъять и есть связь с другими словами.

Comment: Не удержался сообщить, что "из-за того" союз и перед ним запятая не ставится. Почему у вас всегда так много ошибок? Не пойму...

Comment: Ваш способ работает только перед глаголом. "Коммуны как итог (в итоге, итогом) краха всей цивилизации." - вообще здесь не работает, как и во многих других случаях.

Comment: *По этой причине я добавил, что нельзя изъять и есть связь с другими словами* - по какой?! Поняли, что ерунду написали?! И пожалуйста, не захламляйте комментарии под моим ответом обсуждением того, что относится к вашему.

Comment: *вообще здесь не работает, как и во многих других случаях* - что не работает?! Вы вообще поняли, что написали?! Разве я предлагал здесь обобособлять?

Comment: Да я уже понял, что логика у вас вообще не работает. В который раз нужно по 10 раз всё объяснять. Больше не собираюсь.

Comment: *Да я уже понял, что логика у вас вообще не работает* - А у вас работает? Все, хорош поясничать. И передайте своим клонам, что у модераторов есть средство отслеживания слишком уж откровенного жульничества.

Comment: Что за клоны? У меня только один аккаунт... Зачем больше?